# Why does this instrumentation amplifier (INA110KUG) output 9.8 volts even when input voltage is 0V? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: operational-amplifier, instrumentation-amplifier

[image: Op-amp taken from context]

I've tried removing the resistors from the upper side but there was no change in output voltage.

Datasheet:https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina110.pdf

Comment: Why have you connected Output Sense (pin-10) to Output Offset Adjust (pin-15) instead of the Output (pin-9)?

Comment: And why are you not using a standard 'triangle' amplifier symbol for the INA110 in your schematic like the examples in the datasheet? Part of the purpose of a schematic is conveying information to other humans, so using standardized symbols for standard functions makes this easier and more efficient. That plain yellow block with pins in seemingly arbitrary locations makes it unnecessarily difficult to parse.

Comment: Are the two inputs connected to GND (good) or just shorted but floating (bad)?

Comment: @brhans pin 15 is an output pin dedicated for feedback, that's why i connected it like that. Also, I use the symbol like that because that is how it was available in Altium.

Comment: @Jens They are not connected to ground, they are reading the voltage across a 1 Ohm shunt resistor through which no current is passing. The shunt is placed between the load and ground, so the voltage across it is zero (measured).

Comment: Where do you get the idea that "pin 15 is an output pin dedicated for feedback"? There's no indication of that in the datasheet and none of the datasheet example circuits use it in that way. Pin-10 (Output Sense) should be connected to pin-9 (Output). Also, creating new schematic symbols in Altium is not hard.

Comment: @brhans i think that might be one of the mistakes on my part, thank you for pointing that out. I see what you mean and i believe the confusion comes from the Altium symbol - i imagined that pin 9 from the symbol is the "main output" and pin 15 would be a "sensing output."

Rookie mistake, i will change the PCB connections and see if there is a difference. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Pins 1 and 2 are very high impedance inputs. By connecting them together you are certainly making the *difference* in potential equal to zero, but their potential with respect to ground is undefined.

Without an explicit connection to some known potential, this "common-mode" potential is set by whatever influences are in the vicinity, such as radio pickup, mains voltages nearby, and so on.

Consequently, those inputs may be taken outside the amplifier's "common-mode input voltage range", and it will fail to behave as you expect.

You must be explicit not only about the potential *difference* between the two inputs, but also ensure that neither input falls outside the common-mode input voltage range.

As a test, connect both inputs to ground (0V), so that they not only have zero potential difference, but also 0V common-mode potential, which will be well within the amplifier's permitted input range.

Comment: Sorry, my bad on the schematic -> The op-amp is measuring the voltage across a 1Ohm shunt resistor which is placed between a resistive load and ground (GND_Traco on the schematic). 

In my setup, no current is passing through the measurement resistor, so the voltage drop across it is zero. Still, output voltage is 9,8V.